Send file to server Android 13+ kotlin
I'm trying to get a list of all the files on the device, then select one and send it to the server, but I'm getting an error after selecting a file
override fun onResultSelectDocument() {
    isFile = true

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.setType("*/*")
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    resultLauncher.launch(intent)
}

private fun registerResult(){
    resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) {
        try{
            if(it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val result = it.data!!.data!!

                    val sd = AppFile.getFileName(requireActivity(), result)// get a name [name.pdf]
                    val path = AppFile.getPath(requireActivity(), result) // get a ptch [/storage/......./name.pdf]

                    imagePath = path

                    val fullSizeImage = File(imagePath)

                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                        DatabaseAPI.onUploadFile(
                            jobs.jobId,
                            sd.toString().replace("/",""),
                            fullSizeImage) { result, element ->
                            context?.let {
                                //
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ex : Exception){
            Log.e("onActivityResult", ex.message.toString())
        }
    }
}

   fun onUploadFile(
        jobId : Int,
        fileName : String,
        file : File,
        function: (result : RequestResult, element : JobsFiles?) -> (Unit)){
        // Do the POST request and get response
        try {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService()

                val reqFile = file.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())

                val requestBodyBuilder = MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("jobId", jobId.toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("file", fileName, reqFile)

                val requestBody = requestBodyBuilder.build()

                val response = retrofit.onUploadFile(
                    requestBody,"Bearer " + getToken.refresh)

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (ex : Exception){
            Log.e("onUploadFile", ex.message.toString())
        }
    }

This code returns an error:

/storage/emulated/0/Download/mining_guide.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I know that in Android 12 and above a different approach is now needed, but I still could not find the right solution.
It seems to me that before sending it to the server, I need to save the file to the application folder, but I don’t know how to do this

As is mentioned in the accepted answer there, see https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html and https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/ for more details, code samples, etc.

@CommonsWare What should I send to the private val ContentResolver: ContentResolver?

getContentResolver() is a method on Context -- you call that to get a ContentResolver. In this sample app, referenced in this blog post, I happen to be using AndroidViewModel, and I call getApplication() to get the Application singleton Context.
